# NodeJS http-proxy: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT error when proxying https

Tags: node.js, https, http-proxy

I'm following online examples using the latest version of nodejs and http-proxy, but get the following error when my request is sent to the endpoint https server:

```
C:\Users\Me\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\index.js:114
throw err;       
Error: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1370:32)
at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:982:10)
at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:469:13)
at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
at write (_stream_readable.js:582:24)
```

My code is very simple:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var apimcert = fs.readFileSync('./mycert.pfx');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

var options = {
  pfx: apimcert,
  passphrase : 'pAssw0rd',
  rejectUnauthorized : 'false',
  agent: false
};

var server = require('https').createServer(options, function(req, res) {
  console.log("Got a request " + req);
  proxy.web(req, res, {
      ssl: {
        pfx : apimcert,
        passphrase : 'pAssw0rd',
        rejectUnauthorized : 'false'

        //strictSSL: false
      },
      target: 'https://endpointhost:9443/postev',  
      secure: true       
  }

  );
});

console.log("listening on port 9442")
server.listen(9442);
```

If I set `secure : false` then the request does get forwarded to the endpoint, but obviously gets sent back with a 403 forbidden response.  The certificate and passphrase I'm using are the ones from my endpoint server, and I've tested that they do work when sending the request directly.  All I want my proxy to do is to examine the contents of the requests, log a message for each one, and then forward to the endpoint server.

I've googled this problem and tried fiddling around with agents and strictSSL, but to no avail.

Answer (score 15):

I'm using `Ant design pro`with `umi`.
just add this `secure: false,` to `proxy.ts`

```js
proxy: {
  '/myapi': {
      target: 'https://localhost:8443',
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false, // 不进行证书验证
    },
```

umi will auto reload config, just fresh the browser and all good.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `{rejectUnauthorized: false}` to `httpProxy.createProxyServer()`

Comment: thanks, I gave it a try but it didn't help.  I'm thinking there must be a bug in this node-http-proxy package, so looking for alternatives.

Comment: Didn't work in Angular's proxy.conf.js, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## react create app

## file package.json

```
"proxy": {

```
"/credit": {
  "target": "https://xxxx.com",
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "secure": false
}
```

}
```

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

In Nuxt.js when connecting to an API with a self-signed cert, adding this entry to .env will fix the "DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT" error.

`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue - if you look at the `http-node-proxy` source you'll see it actually sets `rejectUnauthorized` based on your `secure` setting in the options:

`if (options[forward || 'target'].protocol == 'https:') {
    outgoing.rejectUnauthorized = (typeof options.secure === "undefined") ? true : options.secure;
}`

So you can actually easily set `rejectUnauthorized` to `false` by just passing `secure: false` in your call to `httpProxy.createProxyServer`.

Comment: The OP specifically mentions that it works when `secure: false` is set. But They probably want to make it work securely.

Answer (score -1):

the easy way is just adding this in your code ,

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

that solved my problem